# Call JS function in php array

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I already loaded the .js file with "myFunction" but i don't know how to call the js function inside the php code. When i view the source it just shows onclick="". How can i fix this?

```
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary' ,
        'items_wrap' => 
            '<ul class="topnav">
                <li class="home" id="home">
                    <a href="' . get_home_url() . '">Startseite</a>
                </li>
                %3$s
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
                </li>
            </ul>'
        ));
    ?>
```

Comment: something up here, it should say `onclick="myFunction()"`, nothing to do with the code above if its removed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make the following changes to your code?

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="myLink">&#9776;</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("myLink").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
```

Just make sure not to bind the EventListener until the page has loaded.